# Count Number of Happy Strings

Tags: combinatorics

A happy string is:

- 6 characters long
- has exactly one digit 0-9
- has exactly one special character from:! @ # $ % ^
- the rest are lowercase letters a-z
- it does not contain two of the same letters

Count the number of happy strings that can be made.

My initial thought is $10\cdot6\cdot26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23$ but I'm afraid I don't take into account the order these characters appear (especially where the digit and special character go).

Comment: to take the order into account just multiply your result by the number of arrangement of 6 characters, i.e. $6!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is good, but lacks a factor of $(6 \times 5)$ which represents that there are $6$ positions where the number can go, and then $5$ remaining positions where the character can go.

So, the final computation is in fact

$$(6 \times 5) \times 10 \times 6 \times \frac{(26)!}{(22)!}.$$

The rightmost fraction above, represents :

- the number of ways of selecting the $4$ alphabetic characters
- sampling **without** replacement
- where order of selection **is** deemed relevant
- and where the positions that the $4$ alphabetic characters will be placed is fixed.   
  The positions of the $4$ alphabetic characters are fixed, once the position of the numeric character and the special character are determined.

My answer agrees with your analysis exactly, except for the $(6 \times 5)$ factor that you omitted.

Answer (score 1):

First choose your characters, then order them:

1. ${{10}\choose 1}$ for selecting one digit
2. ${6\choose 1}$ for selecting one special digit
3. ${{26}\choose 4}$ for selecting four different lowercase letters

Therefore, you have ${{10}\choose 1}{6\choose 1}{{26}\choose 4}$ for choosing the characters as a ***set***.

Since you want to also order them you multiply this answer by $6!$.